# How to get the hardwareIDs of a device without a driver?

Tags: c#, driver, wmi

I'm currently writing a driverscan solution for older systems like XP and vista and I would like to get a list of the hardwareIds of a device for which no driver is installed.

SELECT * FROM Win32_PNPEntity returns the list of HardwareIDs, only if a driver is installed for the device.

Here is my code:

```
string txt = "SELECT * FROM win32_PNPEntity";

        ManagementObjectSearcher deviceSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", txt);
        foreach (ManagementObject device in deviceSearch.Get())
        {
            if (device["Status"].ToString() != "OK")
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var item in device.Properties)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ": " + item.Value);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("HardwareIDs:");
                    foreach (string id in (string[])device["HardwareID"]) { Console.WriteLine(id); }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: WMI is Windows Management Instrumentation. It will only recognize what is installed. Now I noticed you have a txt file. What Does it contain? If it's a list of compatible ID's then you would need to call the HID (Hardware ID) to the txt file of CID (Compatible ID)

Comment: No the string I store the querry in is just called txt. So if WMI can only show information of what is installed, where does the device manager get its information from?

Comment: Let's say you have an ID and the ID is out of date. MS has servers with all of the ID settings. That pertains to MS. Now let's say you go to the system manufacturers website, say HP , you look at the drivers, there is a note that says backup computer before installing driver. Because a computer only matches ID to ID whether it's MS or the manufacturer website. They have a server list with compatible and non compatible ID lists.

Comment: So in theory, ID xXxX is compatible with ID oxoxo then it will update. If it's not it will say it can't be installed. When you go to device manager and update a device it connects to the MS Server, some device ID connects to the manufacturer website. Most device ID is set in the BIOS of what it should have, that's how that works. For the long way what your trying to do is take device ID that is not compatible with the Model and list those. That is too much to do. The model device ID it takes would be simple to achieve and less coding.

Comment: Besides the fact that if MS does not list a device ID means that that device model is not compatible with other ID. If you look at the device manager and look at the properties there is several things to look at. I am in the process of making a System Control Monitor that lets me see what is installed hardware and software. There is two sides to this Hardware and Software. The hardware ID has to be compatible with the OS. That is why there is a compatibility mode. You cannot use device drivers from XP on Windows. You can but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Devices change from year to year, to your list of drivers not installed on a System would go on forever. Because there is a lot more non compatible drivers VS compatible drivers to a model. Does that make sense?

Comment: In other words, look at the properties of a driver in device manager. There is literally 100 ID's per driver. Those all coincide with each other. If you delete or uninstall a System driver and restart the computer it automatically installs it. Because those are tied to the motherboard, OS and registry. So there is a lot more to the device ID that meets the eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library for this. It is extremely simple to solve.

1) Define your class:

```
public class Win32_PnPEntity
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

2) Access WMI:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

List<Win32_PnPEntity> devices = helper.Query<Win32_PnPEntity>().ToList().Where(p => p.Status == "Error");
```